# CefSharp отказывается программно нажать на кнопку через JS

Tags: c#, click, cefsharp

У меня есть 2 функции:

```
    public void Click(string xpath)
    {
        var js = "document.evaluate(\"" + xpath + "\", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().click();";

        EvaluateJavascript(js);
    }

    public void ClickCss(string css)
    {
        var js = "document.querySelector('"+ css + "').click()";

        EvaluateJavascript(js);
    }

    //доп.функция
    public async Task EvaluateJavascript(string script)
    {
        JavascriptResponse javascriptResponse = await Browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

        if (!javascriptResponse.Success)
        {
            throw new JavascriptException(javascriptResponse.Message);
        }
    }
```

Я вижу довольно странное поведение:

- на простые линки кликает нормально и из Консоли Разработчика Браузера и из CEFSharp
- при этом у меня есть на странице кнопка которая прекрасно нажимается из КРБ, но при этом отказывается работать в CEF-e почему-то.

Есть идеи в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в security limitations которые накладываются на запускаемый в браузере JS. То есть нельзя кликнуть на кнопку, которая открывает опен файл диалог

Решение проблемы:

1. Взять координаты с помощью JS
2. Кликнуть по даным координатам в CEF:

   ```
   public void MouseClick(int x, int y)
   {
       Browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
       Thread.Sleep(15);
       Browser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(x, y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
   }
   ```